# Can I use Bing Autosuggest with Custom Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

Can I use the Bing [Autosuggest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-autosuggest-api-v7-reference) in conjunction with Bing [Custom Search](https://www.customsearch.ai/) to get custom filtered results, or does it necessarily give regular Bing results (Web Search API)?

I couldn't find anything about this in the docs or forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for now, the Bing Autosuggest API is generic and is meant to be used in conjunction with the Bing Web Search API. Having said that, you can always use the Bing Autosuggest API with the Bing Custom Search API, if you are getting valid query completion suggestions from the Bing Autosuggest API.

Bing Custom Search API will always return results from the domains/subsites/webpages you have configured, so no issues there. Just that the Bing Autosuggest responses may not be meant for the configured domains only.

Comment: Thank you. Is that a planned feature, as the `searchKind` field in the Autossuggest response object seems to imply?

Comment: Yeah, there are indications from the autosuggest response object and the fact that Custom Search doesn't provide 'related searches' back as Web Search API does. Should be in the backlog.